# cout is not a member of std

Tags: c++, io, std, member, cout

I'm practicing using mulitple files and header files etc. So I have this project which takes two numbers and then adds them. Pretty simple.

Here are my files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
    int x = readNumber();
    int y = readNumber();

    writeAnswer(x + y);

    return(0);
}
```

**io.cpp**

```
int readNumber()
{
    int x;

    std::cout << "Number: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

void writeAnswer(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Answer: ";
    std::cout << x;
}
```

**add.h**

```
#ifndef ADD_H_INCLUDED
#define ADD_H_INCLUDED

int readNumber();
void writeAnswer(int x);

#endif // #ifndef ADD_H_INCLUDED
```

The error is showing up in io.cpp. The exact errors are:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? Thanks.

**EDIT: I made a small project yesterday with the same amount of files (2 .cpp and 1.h) and I didn't include the iostream header in the other .cpp and it still compiled and ran fine.**

Comment: Re your edit: then you compiled that project differently. Including iostream in your second cpp file is **required** as you have it here. Maybe you had that include in the `.h` file last time around.

Comment: Yeah, it's working great now, thanks for the quick responses everyone! :)

Comment: always include system header files after your local files.

Answer (score 432, accepted):

add `#include <iostream>` to the start of `io.cpp` too.

Comment: iostream has to be included (directly or indirectly). Otherwise how would the compiler know where to find std::cout.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Thanks. Though how did I get my other proj. to work without including it in the other .cpp too? I updated OP at the bottom.

Comment: You´ve probably included it indirectly. It is ALWAYS required.

Comment: I needed to include it in a .h file as well!! Thanks

Comment: also it has to be included after `stdafx.h`, not before

Answer (score 27):

If you're using pre-compiled headers with Microsoft's compiler (MSVC), remember that it must be:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
```

and not the other way around:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
```

In other words, the pre-compiled header include file must always come first. (The compiler should give you an error specifically explaining this if you forget.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that i had to add an extra entry in `cmake` to include the files.

Since i was also using the zmq library I had to add this to the included libraries as well.